# Max power transfer of source with variable internal resistance

Tags: power-supply, internal-resistance

I have been reading how to obtain maximum external power from a source using the maximum power transfer theorem. However, it is for a source with a finite internal resistance.

1. Can you have power sources with a variable internal resistance?
2. How would you find (or calculate) the maximum external power of a source with a variable internal resistance (Theoretically, if you can't have a power source with a variable internal resistance)

Comment: Variable internal resistance is a thing, and batteries do experience it. For example, the internal resistance of alkaline cells can rise dramatically (e.g. 4x) when they are nearly flat. IR can also depend on temperature.

Comment: So you would calculate the maximum external power transfer of a variable resistance power source the same way?

Comment: I think you are confused somehow. The maximum power transfer theorem is not used very widely, lots in school teaching, but in practical world very little. The proof is the mains, you do connect various loads with different resistances, so what?

Comment: @BrianDrummond MPPT and maximum power transfer theorem is totally different story.